# how to split one column into many columns and count the frequency

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Here is the question I have in mind, given a table

```
   Id   type
0   1    [a,b]
1   2     [c]
2   3     [a,d]
```

I want to convert it into the form of:

```
   Id     a  b  c  d
0   1     1  1  0  0
1   2     0  0  1  0
2   3     1  0  0  1
```

I need a very efficient way to convert a large table. any comment is welcome.

====================================

I have received several good answers, and really appreciate your help.

Now a new question comes along, which is my laptop memory is insufficient to generating the whole dataframe by using `pd.dummies`.

is there anyway to generate a sparse vector row by row and stack then together?

Comment: Do you know all the possible values that can occur in `type` beforehand?

Comment: @shanmuga, yes, I can calculate all the distinct types quickly beforehand

Comment: Is your `type` column made up of strings or lists of strings?

Comment: @DSM, it is list in the json file, when I read it into data frame, it becomes the string, but the `[` sign is kept.

Comment: So `print(type(df["type"].iloc[0]))` gives `<class 'str'>`?

Comment: @DSM, oh, your intuition is right, it is list, I though data frame can only keep numeric, boolean, and string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
>>> df
   Id    type
0   1  [a, b]
1   2     [c]
2   3  [a, d]
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([x for x in df['type'].apply(
...           lambda item: dict(map(
...                                 lambda x: (x,1), 
...                             item)) 
...           ).values]).fillna(0)
>>> df2.join(df)
   a  b  c  d  Id    type
0  1  1  0  0   1  [a, b]
1  0  0  1  0   2     [c]
2  1  0  0  1   3  [a, d]
```

It basically convert the list of list to list of dict and construct a DataFrame out of this

> [ ['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['a', 'd'] ]  # list of list
>   [ {'a':1, 'b':1}, {'c':1}, {'a':1, 'd':1} ] # list of dict
>   Make DataFrame out of this

Comment: @3c. how large is your data? How many rows and number of distinct values for type? I tested it with 1 million rows and 4 distinct values. It finished in 4-6 seconds.

Comment: 40,000 rows, and about 7000 colunms. This table should not be big in size, but my 4G memory laptop generates insufficient memory when using `pd.get_dummies`

Comment: @3c. 4GB should be sufficient to process this. If you are hitting memory error your code needs more optimization.

Comment: I also tried you suggestion using `df.type.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([1]*len(x), index=x)) `. However, since some entries in the type list takes the form of `'Old El Paso\u2122 mild red enchilada sauce'`. Thus  I received `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`.

Seems like the `\u2122` makes the reindexing invalid.

Comment: @3c. use utf-8 encoding to read the file. `fin = open('a.json', encoding='utf-8'); df = pd.read_json(fin);`

Comment: your answer fits into my memory. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.type.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([i for i in x])))
```

to explain:

```
df.type.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([i for i in x]
```

gets you a column for index position in your lists. You can then use `get dummies` to get the count of each value

```
pd.get_dummies(df.type.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([i for i in x])))
```

outputs:

```
    a   c   b   d
0   1   0   1   0
1   0   1   0   0
2   1   0   0   1
```

Comment: this is really succinct and nice. Thanks a lot. The only problem is my computer is out of memory. Maybe I can switch to a desktop with 16GB memory, or can I store the dummies matrix into sparse form?

Comment: if it a string, not a list then you can use the string method `split()`. I have added it to the answer (you might need to deal with the square brackets first

Comment: @JAB you could avoid making dummies by modifying the code as `df.type.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([1]*len(x), index=x))`

Comment: @JAB, my bad, it is list not string.

Comment: @shanmuga that is a neater approach

Comment: I'm not sure I see the point of `.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([i for i in x]))`.  Wouldn't `.apply(pd.Series)` produce exactly the same thing?