# Splitting one column into many, counting frequency: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, iterable

This is my first question on stack overflow and it may be a bit clunky as I learn the ropes - tips or pointers in question formatting welcome!

I'm very new to python and have an issue nearly identical to the one below:

[how to split one column into many columns and count the frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596216/how-to-split-one-column-into-many-columns-and-count-the-frequency)

For my data, I have two columns, "logger" and "page", where logger is a column of IP addresses in non-null object string format, and page is a randomized 1-10 non-null int number that represents a webpage the logger visited. An example of this is below:

```
  logger        page
0 10.1.60.203   3
1 3.75.190.181  5
2 10.1.60.203   4
3 10.1.60.203   6
4 10.1.60.253   1
```

What I'd like to do is to is to have one row for each unique IP in the logger column, and to have a series of columns from 1-10 representing the total count of page views for each page for each IP address, which are then counted for each column, like below:

```
  logger        page1  page2  page3  page4  page5 ...
0 10.1.60.203   5      7      14     7      2
1 3.75.190.181  10     3      20     8      6
2 10.1.60.253   22     9      2      12     18
```

I've tried a lot of different options to work through this - pivot tables, groupby, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to get the counts into their respective unique columns per IP address. When I came upon the other forum I felt that that answer should work quite well, but unfortunately I'm coming across the error that 'int' object is not iterable. Here is the code from that user that I'm currently working with:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([x for x in df['page'].apply(
...           lambda item: dict(map(
...                                 lambda x: (x,1), 
...                             item)) 
...           ).values]).fillna(0) 
>>> df2.join(df)
```

I can somewhat grasp what the aforementioned error means but am not confident in ability to work out the answer from there. Any help with this error or particular, or with a more broad solution to my problem, would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What's the result of your `df['page'].apply(...)` call?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Hi Patrick, the result of my `df['page'].apply(...)` is: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
         logger  page
0   10.1.60.203     3
1  3.75.190.181     5
2   10.1.60.203     4
3   10.1.60.203     6
4   10.1.60.253     1

In [9]: df.pivot_table(index='logger', columns='page', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
Out[9]:
page          1  3  4  5  6
logger
10.1.60.203   0  1  1  0  1
10.1.60.253   1  0  0  0  0
3.75.190.181  0  0  0  1  0
```

Comment: Yes - thank you so much!! This saved hours of work....I think that this entire time I must have just been misunderstanding `aggfunc='size'`, using it after grouping the logger.